# Prevent jumping to first frame when video source changes

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

My code is as follows

```js
"use strict";
console.clear();

((d,w) => {
  const cloneVideo = vid => {
    const clone = vid.cloneNode(true);
    clone.id += '-'
    clone.style.display = 'none'
    vid.parentElement.insertBefore(clone, vid);
    return clone;
  }
  
  const getVideoSources = el => Array.from(el.querySelectorAll(":scope > source"));

  const isTypeSupported = type => d.createElement("video").canPlayType(type);

  const isMatchMedia = media => w.matchMedia(media).matches;

  const onLoadeddata = (vid, clone) => e => {
    const t = vid.currentTime;
    vid.remove()
    clone.currentTime = t;
    clone.style.display = ''
    clone.removeEventListener('loadeddata', onLoadeddata(vid, clone))
    clone.play();
  }
  
  const updateVideoSources = vid => {
    let changes = getVideoSources(vid).findIndex(src => isMatchMedia(src.media))
    if (changes > 0) {
      const clone = cloneVideo(vid);
      let changes = getVideoSources(clone).filter(src => isMatchMedia(src.media))
      changes.reverse().forEach(src => clone.prepend(src))
      const id = vid.id
      clone.addEventListener('loadeddata', onLoadeddata(vid, clone))
      clone.load();
      
      
      clone.id = id
      return clone
    }
    return vid
  };

  const checkMedia = (video) => {
    return (e) => {
      // console.log(e)
      video = updateVideoSources(video);
      // console.log(39, video, video.parentElement)
    }
  }

  w.checkMedia = checkMedia;

  
})(document,window);

{
  const delay = 250;
  const video = document.getElementById("vid");
  const check = checkMedia(video)
  

  window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", check);
  window.addEventListener("resize", debounce(check, delay));

  // Returns a function, that, as long as it continues to be invoked, will not
  // be triggered. The function will be called after it stops being called for
  // N milliseconds. If `immediate` is passed, trigger the function on the
  // leading edge, instead of the trailing.
  function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
    var timeout;
    return function () {
      var context = this,
        args = arguments;
      var later = function () {
        timeout = null;
        if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
      };
      var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
      clearTimeout(timeout);
      timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
      if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
    };
  }
}
```

```css
.container {
  max-width: 925px;
  margin: auto;
}

.clip {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
}
.clip:before {
  content: '';
  padding-bottom: calc(100% * 506 / 448);
  visibility: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
  flex-basis: 0;
}
.clip:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #c3a88c;
  background: #8a5d2f;
  background: #ca935a;
  background: #af8457;
  mix-blend-mode: soft-light;
  -webkit-clip-path: circle(farthest-side at 56.4% 50%);
          clip-path: circle(farthest-side at 56.4% 50%);
}

#vid {
  -webkit-clip-path: circle(farthest-side at 56.4% 50%);
          clip-path: circle(farthest-side at 56.4% 50%);
  -o-object-fit: cover;
     object-fit: cover;
  -o-object-position: 56.4% 50%;
     object-position: 56.4% 50%;
}

#vid {
  line-height: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="clip">
    <video id="vid" autoplay muted loop playsinline preload="auto" width="100%" height="auto">
      <source data-number="1" src="https://assets.codepen.io/96344/pleyces-landing-page-video_240p.webm" type="video/webm" media="(max-width:527px)">
      <source data-number="2" src="https://assets.codepen.io/96344/pleyces-landing-page-video_240p.ogv" type="video/ogg" media="(max-width:527px)">
      <source data-number="3" src="https://assets.codepen.io/96344/pleyces-landing-page-video_240p.mp4" type="video/mp4" media="(max-width:527px)">
      <source data-number="4" src="https://assets.codepen.io/96344/pleyces-landing-page-video_360p.webm" type="video/webm" media="(max-width: 719px) and (min-width:528px)">
      <source data-number="5" src="https://assets.codepen.io/96344/pleyces-landing-page-video_360p.ogv" type="video/ogg" media="(max-width: 719px) and (min-width:528px)">
      <source data-number="6" src="https://assets.codepen.io/96344/pleyces-landing-page-video_360p.mp4" type="video/webm" media="(max-width: 719px) and (min-width:528px)">
      <source data-number="7" src="https://assets.codepen.io/96344/pleyces-landing-page-video_480p.webm" type="video/webm" media="(max-width: 899px) and (min-width:720px)">
      <source data-number="8" src="https://assets.codepen.io/96344/pleyces-landing-page-video_480p.ogv" type="video/ogg" media="(max-width: 899px) and (min-width:720px)">
      <source data-number="9" src="https://assets.codepen.io/96344/pleyces-landing-page-video_480p.mp4" type="video/mp4" media="(max-width: 899px) and (min-width:720px)">
      <source data-number="10" src="https://assets.codepen.io/96344/pleyces-landing-page-video_600p.webm" type="video/webm" media="(min-width:900px)">
      <source data-number="11" src="https://assets.codepen.io/96344/pleyces-landing-page-video_600p.ogv" type="video/ogg" media="(min-width:900px)">
      <source data-number="12" src="https://assets.codepen.io/96344/pleyces-landing-page-video_600p.mp4" type="video/mp4" media="(min-width:900px)">
    </video>

  </div>
</div>
```

#### What this code does?

Since there is no support for `media` attributes of `<source>` elements inside `<video>` elements (See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTML/Element/source#attr-media)), I needed to code a workaround. What I coded is: Listen to resize events (debounced) and check the media queries of each source, if it matches with window `matchMedia`. If some sources match, I change the order of the `<source>` tags and move the matches to be first children of the `<video>` elements.

After that I load the video again and jump to the memorized time.

Because this had the disadvantage of flickering when the sources changed (video disappeared and then appeared again), I needed a workaround. For this I clone the video before sorting and loading and then remove the original video after the clone has loaded (event `loadeddata`).

This prevents the flickering, but has another slight unpleasant behavior. The video jumps to the first video frame and then immediately to the time frame I memorized earlier.

Why does it do that? I set the `currentTime` before the `play()` action.

For this issue to show you need to test this in Full page mode and change the window width: I have three break points defined, where the video source should change: 528, 720 and 900 pixels. You can check that it's working by inspecting the Network tab in your Browser's Developer Tools.

Comment: I'd probably trigger the swap on the canplaythru (after setting currentTime) rather than loadeddata.. just because you have the metadata doesn't mean that buffering has caught up. I'd also try the play before swapping the old and new elements

Comment: @Offbeatmammal Thank you for nudging me in the right direction: I ended up with this: https://codepen.io/HerrSerker/pen/23bd9de38f86fd5223ff6030e1a15575?editors=0010